# Displaying two different images in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I just started working on OpenGL recently. I need help when it comes to displaying two images in separate objects with two different texture units. The first image is rendered twice instead of getting two different images. Please what do you think could be wrong?

```
 int width, height, width1, height1;
    unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image("res/images/image1.jpg", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
    unsigned char* image1 = SOIL_load_image("res/images/image2.jpg", &width1, &height1, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);

    GLuint texture, texture1;

    //Texture0
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    SOIL_free_image_data(image);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    //Texture 1

    glGenTextures(1, &texture1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width1, height1, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image1);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    SOIL_free_image_data(image1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);


    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
        glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        shader.Use();
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "texture0"), 0);
        
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "texture1"), 0); // the variable is the same with that of in core.frag
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 12, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using two different texture units when drawing, but the same texture unit when binding and loading the 2 textures. Either remove `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);` from before drawing or use `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);` before your second texture load

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I really don't understand what you mean.I edited the code to show the texture units

Comment: Maybe you made a mistake in the shader, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57621863/opengl-some-clarification-on-using-multiple-textures-or-texture-units) has a good explanation of what that should look like